# RxJS first operator

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am new to RxJS. I was reading about first operator and understood that it returns the first element from a list/array/sequence or the first element which matches the given predicate.

I have written the below code

```
new Observable<number[]>(s => {s.next([1,2,3,4]);}).pipe(first()).subscribe({
      next: (response) => console.log(response) // prints [1,2,3,4]
    })
```

I was expecting that since my observable is emitting an array and the first operator would only return the first value to the subscribe's next function and 1 would be printed. Instead the complete array is printed.

```
from([1,2,3,4]).pipe(first()).subscribe({next: (res) => console.log(res)}) // prints 1
```

This code works as expected.

How are these two blocks of code different? Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`first` returns first **emitted** value. Your value is the whole array.

`s.next([1,2,3,4])` is equivalent to `of([1,2,3,4])` not `from([1,2,3,4])`.
`from` flattens the values from array and emits them separately, you can achieve the same by using `mergeAll` before `first`

Answer (score 2):

This observable:

```
new Observable<number[]>(s => {
  s.next([1,2,3,4]);
  s.complete();
})
```

Is the same as:

```
of([1,2,3,4])
```

**Here** the first value is an array with some numbers in it (The array [1,2,3,4]).

---

You could write the following:

```
new Observable<number[]>(s => {
  s.next(1);
  s.next(2);
  s.next(3);
  s.next(4);
  s.complete();
})
```

Which would translate into:

```
concat(
  of(1),
  of(2),
  of(3),
  of(4),
)
```

or

```
from([1,2,3,4])
```

**Here** the first value is a number (The number 1)